# caching sql result set in java

Tags: java, sql, caching

I know that caching the resultset of frequently used sql statements is better for the performance I am searching about the best way to cache sql result set in java. I found some codes but, it requires adding new jar files to netbeans. 
Can anybody help me how can do that without needing to additional apis?

Comment: What's wrong with adding the jars to your project?

Comment: surely, It is not wrong. but I search about the simplest way. If using APIs is Inevitable, I will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cache the data only. I would advise you to use an external api because you will probably also need to evict old data from cache(to prevent from using to much memory).

Using [guave](http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?Id=127):

ConcurrentMap _continueContexts = new MapMaker()
    .expiration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .makeMap();

P.S: You should something like maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: All caching related methods on MapMaker have been deprecated in favor of similar methods in CacheBuilder, and are scheduled for upcoming deletion. Release 11.0.0 already removed evictionListener, expireAfterWrite, and expireAfterAccess. Future releases will remove makeComputingMap and expiration. Link : https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/MapMakerMigration

Answer (score 6):

You should cache the resulting objects, not the result sets, because the `ResultSet` has a reference to the connection (via the statement) which often hold an open database connection or is no longer usable after the connection has been closed!

Comment: Plus, there is a limit on the amount of open connections, thus ResultSets, the SQL server is willing to support

Answer (score 0):

You could make a linked list of results. With the cache trigger pointing to the start of the list. Since linked lists act like a wrapper around whatever you want you can make the results as generic as you want.
 This won't require another api but you will have to implement this all on your own and hopefully you understand why we don't like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: ^_^ I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want a simple and practicle method. the main problem is not in using additional APIs. I found many methods and I don't know what is the best.